`QProcess::startDetached` deprecated: any alternatives?
im trying to launch the cmd on windows. i used the following code to launch the terminal, and it worked 100% fine.
but the Qt Creator keep saying that QProcess::startDetached(const QString &) is deprecated, i just dont know why.
ive looked at these (Alternatives to QProcess::startDetached() and QProcess start() as they are deprecated) alternatives but none of it worked as my command require special string handling.
whats worse in qt 6 the deprecated methods are even removed. now i have no way to access this method.
my code (as spoke it works fine but it's deprecated):
void MainWindow::on_actionShowFolderInTerminal(bool isChecked) {
    Q_UNUSED(isChecked)
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN) || defined(Q_OS_WIN32) || defined(Q_OS_WINDOWS)
    QProcess::startDetached("cmd /C start \"\" cmd /K cd /d \"" + (m_editor->absPath()) + "\"");
    return;
#endif
    CriticalMessage::exec("Currently this function is supported in Windows only. We'll add support to macOS and Linux as soon as possible");
}

any help will be appreciated!

the answer on the question you link explains that only some overloads but not the whole functions are deprecated. The ones that are not deprecated have more arguments (not less), hence it is not clear why you cannot use them

Seems like you didn't read the answer in the question you quoted. startDetached is not depracated.

A part of the overloaded QProcess::startDetached, QProcess::startDetached(const QString &) is deprecated in Qt 5.15 and removed in Qt 6 (based on 6.7.1, as far as I know). It is because it's quite unsafe to pass non-segmented command-arguments mixture to the process rather than sliced and arrayed arguments, as the slicing and separating work for the arguments is ambiguous.
Back to the topic, @pptaszni suggested a good way to tackle your problem:
void MainWindow::on_actionShowFolderInTerminal(bool isChecked) {
    Q_UNUSED(isChecked)
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN) || defined(Q_OS_WIN32) || defined(Q_OS_WINDOWS)
    QProcess::startDetached("cmd /C start \"\" cmd /K cd /d \"" + (m_editor->absPath()) + "\"", {});
    return;
#endif
    CriticalMessage::exec("Currently this function is supported in Windows only. We'll add support to macOS and Linux as soon as possible");
}

Except that if only the original and deprecated QProcess::startDetached(const QString & overloaded method works, but not neither the above answer nor in the Qt official documentation, you can still try:
void MainWindow::on_actionShowFolderInTerminal(bool isChecked) {
    Q_UNUSED(isChecked)
#if defined(Q_OS_WIN) || defined(Q_OS_WIN32) || defined(Q_OS_WINDOWS)
    command = "cmd /C start \"\" cmd /K cd /d \"" + (m_editor->absPath()) + "\"";
    QProcess process;
    QStringList arguments = QProcess::splitCommand(command);
    if (arguments.isEmpty())
        return;
    process.setProgram(arguments.takeFirst());
    process.setArgument(arguments);
    process.startDetached();
    return;
#endif
    CriticalMessage::exec("Currently this function is supported in Windows only. We'll add support to macOS and Linux as soon as possible");
}

The second answer is based on Qt source code. Hope them help.

In Qt5 non-deprecated startDetached method takes at least 2 arguments
bool QProcess::startDetached(const QString &program, const QStringList &arguments, const QString &workingDirectory = QString(), qint64 *pid = nullptr)

So if you want to silence the warning, just change your code to something like
QProcess::startDetached("cmd /C start \"\" cmd /K cd /d \"" + (m_editor->absPath()) + "\"", {});

In Qt6 startDetached signature changed:
bool QProcess::startDetached(const QString &program, const QStringList &arguments = {}, const QString &workingDirectory = QString(), qint64 *pid = nullptr)

and second arg arguments is by default an empty list, so if you leave your code as-is, it will work fine also with Qt6.
